# SQL combine query into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several insert queries:

```
insert into table2 (age, name)
    select '0-19', 'abc'
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 where age is null  and name is null);

insert into table2 (age, name)
    select '20-29', 'zxy'
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 where age not in ( '0-19')  and name is null);

insert into table2 (age, name)
    select '30-39', 'egt'
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 where age not in ( '0-19', '20-29')  and name is null);

insert into table2 (age, name)
    select '40-49', 'aaa'
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 where age not in ( '0-19', '20-29', '30-39')  and name is null);

insert into table2 (age, name)
    select '50-59', 'rtg'
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 where age not in ( '0-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49')  and name is null);

insert into table2 (age, name)
    select '60+', 'ghg'
    where not exists (select 1 from table2 where age not in ( '0-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-59')  and name is null);
```

I  want to insert data if the relevant condition is met. You can see they separate query. Rewrite these queries into one query. Thank you

I can try to test with anyone can rework these queries regardless `nvarchar` or `integer`.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.  These queries don't really make sense to me.

Comment: I  want to insert data if  condition is met . you can see they seperate query. Rewrite these queries into one query.

Comment: Sorry but storing integer values, those of `age` column, is not a good idea.

Comment: all nvarchar not integer

Comment: I mean that why dont you store each of them as independent integer values. You can look for intervals among those integer values whenever needed rather than storing them interval-like strings.

Comment: Can you rewrite the query in any way to make it work? I can try your way

Comment: *"all nvarchar not integer "* that's even worse, @qphan . Someone who is 9 is *not* older than someone who is `75`, however, `'9'` *is* greater than `'75`' (or in your case `N'9'` and `N'75'` respectively). Then we get onto the fact that storing an `nvarchar` when you are storing non-ANSI characters is also a fast of storage.

Comment: @qphan . . . What does inserting a *new* name have to do with whether a non-`NULL` `name` (which might be different) already exists?

Comment: If name is blank and age blank  then insert , if name is match age blank then not insert

Comment: You can `union` them all together to make a single `insert` but why do you want to do that?

Comment: I can union but I want a better way to make it shorter and  use less space. Not sure any one can use IIF or CASE or something?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether below helps.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN Age IN ("00-19") 
     THEN ("0-19")
     ELSE ("NULL")
    END AS Age,
    CASE WHEN Age IN ("20-29") 
     THEN ("20-29")
     ELSE ("NULL")
    END AS Age,
    CASE WHEN Age IN ("30-39") 
     THEN ("30-39")
     ELSE ("NULL")
    END AS Age,
    CASE WHEN Age IN ("40-49") 
     THEN ("40-49")
     ELSE ("NULL")
    END AS Age,
    CASE WHEN Age IN ("50-59") 
     THEN ("50-59")
     ELSE ("NULL")
    END AS Age,
    CASE WHEN Age IN ("60-69") 
     THEN ("60-69")
     ELSE ("NULL")
    END AS Age
FROM table2
```

I don't know whether above helps. Would encourage you to explain what you are trying to do as then everyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:  Create a table variable to store your ranges and then join the temp variable to the table you want to insert the missing values, for example:

```
-- your Table2
Declare @table2 TABLE (age varchar(10), name varchar(10))

-- a temp variable table to join in order to exclude the duplicates
Declare @data TABLE (age varchar(10), name varchar(10))

    -- add all the values you want to verify existence of
    INSERT INTO @data SELECT '0-19', 'abc'
    INSERT INTO @data SELECT '20-29', 'zxy'
    INSERT INTO @data SELECT '30-39', 'egt'
    INSERT INTO @data SELECT '40-49', 'aaa'
    INSERT INTO @data SELECT '50-59', 'rtg'
    INSERT INTO @data SELECT '60+', 'ghg'

    --  before the insert (all the missing values)
    SELECT d.age, d.[name] 
        FROM @data d 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @table2 t ON d.age = t.age 
        WHERE t.age IS NULL

    -- do the insert
    INSERT INTO @Table2 
    SELECT d.age, d.[name] 
        FROM @data d 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @table2 t ON d.age = t.age 
        WHERE t.age IS NULL

    -- this should now be empty
    SELECT d.age, d.[name] 
        FROM @data d 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @table2 t ON d.age = t.age 
        WHERE t.age IS NULL
```

Version 1:
Can you show us the data that is stored in the table?  Doing range searches on an age that is stored as a string might work like you think it should.

*For example:*
'0-19'

Is the data stored as '5' in your table or '0-19'?  If it is stored as '5' then as others have already mentioned, it's a great idea to convert that data type to numeric data type (small int or int).

Here's an example, have you ever sorted values that are stored as string (varchar) however represent a number?  For example, if we had this set of values we expect the sort to come back as:

```
 1,2,3,100,200,300
```

However we get:

```
 1,100,2,200,3,300
```

In order to sort the string properly, you will have to pad to the right up to the longest length.

In this case 3 characters.

```
 001 002, 003, 100, 200, 300.
```

In a string, each character is evaluated.

If you look at the ASCII table (https://www.ascii-code.com/) you get an idea why.
NULL is ahead of the numbers.

```
1 = 49 0 0
100 = 49 48 48
2 = 50 0 0
200 = 50 48 48
```